# Can you open a directory without blocking on I/O?

Tags: c, linux

I'm working on a Linux/C application with strict timing requirements.  I want to open a directory for reading without blocking on I/O (i.e. succeed only if the information is immediately available in cache).  If this request would block on I/O I would like to know so that I can abort and ignore this directory for now.  I know that open() has a non-blocking option O_NONBLOCK.  However, it has this caveat:

```
Note that this flag has no effect for regular files and
              block devices; that is, I/O operations will (briefly)
              block when device activity is required, regardless of
              whether O_NONBLOCK is set.
```

I assume that a directory entry is treated like a regular file.  I don't know of a good way to prove/disprove this.  Is there a way to open a directory without any I/O blocking?

Comment: You may nead threads here.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - Ideally yes, however due to some limitations placed on the application using threads is not a good option in my case.

Comment: Linux has terrible support for asynchronous disk I/O - unlike Windows which supports it properly!. The general recommendation is to use threads. Or Windows.

Comment: _I assume that a directory entry is treated like a regular file._ Internally, in the kernel, perhaps. But, while you can do `open` on a directory with `O_RDONLY`, doing `read` is problematic. You need `getdents`. But, reading entries with `getdents` _is_ non-blocking by its nature. There's no legit/easy way to determine if the data is already in the page/buffer cache. Just do the `open` in a different _thread_ [which may block]. It can post status in memory. The main thread can skip based on that. But, IMO, just open the dir and take the "hit". Again, multithreading may help, but ...

Comment: _Why_ can't you use threads? What are the limitations? Normally, reading dirs is I/O bound anyway, so I'm not sure what you gain by continuing the program if the data isn't already in the cache. The small overhead of waiting is absorbed by the disk overhead of reading the entries. If the data is not in the cache, you have to do `open/getdents` to "load" the cache. So, somebody has to do that (hence the extra thread).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `COPROC` command in linux to run a process in background. Maybe it could work for you.